# remove extra space/margin after navigator highstocks

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using highstocks in my application where I have following options of highstock chart.

```
   rangeSelector: {
        enabled: false
      },
      scrollbar: {
        enabled: false
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Dummy Data Set'
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      series: [{
        tooltip: {
          valueDecimals: 2
        },
        name: 'AAPL',
        data: [
          ...
        ]
      }]
```

HTML template is like this

```
<div style="border: 1px black solid" class='container'></div>
```

I am getting an ohlc stock chart but have extra space/margin at the bottom after navigator.

[image: Highstock Demo]

Is there any way to remove that extra space/margin.

Comment: what does the `container` class contain?

Comment: have you tried with CSS? giving your container a height of 100%? .container{height: 100%;margin: 0;} since I guess your container includes your chart

Comment: @VíñịtVịłłă in container, I have rendered the chart.

Comment: @mrdeadsven I have inspected over the div using dev tools and I come to know that extra space/margin over there coming from any default property or option from the chart. div is only having border property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the space between the bottom edge of the chart and the content by setting appropriate `chart.spacingBottom` value.

Code:

```js
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  chart: {
    spacingBottom: 5
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  rangeSelector: {
    selected: 1
  },
  title: {
    text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'AAPL',
    data: [
      [1539264600000, 214.45],
      [1539351000000, 222.11],
      [1539610200000, 217.36],
      [1539696600000, 222.15],
      [1539783000000, 221.19],
      [1539869400000, 216.02],
      [1539955800000, 219.31],
      [1540215000000, 220.65],
      [1540301400000, 222.73],
      [1540387800000, 215.09],
      [1540474200000, 219.8],
      [1540560600000, 216.3],
      [1540819800000, 212.24],
      [1540906200000, 213.3],
      [1540992600000, 218.86],
      [1541079000000, 222.22],
      [1541165400000, 207.48],
      [1541428200000, 201.59],
      [1541514600000, 203.77],
      [1541601000000, 209.95],
      [1541687400000, 208.49],
      [1541773800000, 204.47],
      [1542033000000, 194.17],
      [1542119400000, 192.23],
      [1542205800000, 186.8]
    ],
    tooltip: {
      valueDecimals: 2
    }
  }]
});
```

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/krgxL7dv/1/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/chart.spacingBottom

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you so much.